# How do I connect my Alesis iO2 Interface with video camera Nikon D3200?

Tags: audio, conversion

I want to run my condenser microphone through my Alesis iO2 interface directly into my D3200 Nikon video camera, which has a 3.5mm jack input.  Can I simply run a 1/4" output from the Alesis with an adapter into the Nikon's audio input?  Since the Aleis is powered by a USB into my computer, I am curious whether such a configuration will work?  I am very new to the recording world, so any insights or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  This is a very, very weird objective and there is likely a better way to accomplish whatever you are trying to do.  Why do you need to record the audio in both places?  If you are recording the audio on the PC, you should not need it on camera and vice versa.

Comment: I am trying to make a video with simultaneous audio input into the camera. Ultimately, I will download the video to my computer for editing, etc, but are you implying that I can also run the video into the computer at the same time as inputting the audio and accomplish both inputs at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Im unfamiliar with the iO2, but it sounds as though you're basically wanting to use it as a preamp; you almost certainly *can* set up it so the inputs are mirrored back to the outputs so you can use it this way, but you will may  need some sort of audio application 'in the middle' to do so.  You'll also need need the computer running for it to work.

Thing is, though, this doesnt really sound like a particularly great way of going about recording your audio, and its certainly not advantageous to have to cart around, and hook up, a computer, just so you can basically misuse a USB soundcard as a preamp.  You'd be better off with a separate preamp.

Plus, if you were utterly determined to use the computer for some reason, you'd probably be better off using *it* to record your audio, rather than the camera; you'd be opting out on two extra stages of conversion between analog and digital for a start.
I think you're going about this the wrong way, though, and a separate battery-powered preamp would  be a simpler, easier approach.